# Print a portion of html page multiple times in php

Tags: php, html

I have html page with following code.

```
    <img id="img_qr" src="<?php echo $src; ?>" style="width:<?php echo $width?>;height:<?php echo $height;  ?>"> 
    <input type="text" id="no_qr" name="no_qr" />
    <input type="button" value="print" onclick="print_qr();" />
```

I need to print the Qr code only. Also i need to print number of times QR code based on the text box value. ie. when input is 10 I need to print QR code 10 times in single page. But when i am doing this whole page is printed and only one Qr code is printed. Please anyone help me.

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: You should edit your question, it's not very clear

Comment: I suspect this'll be better achieved with a loop client-side (JS / JQuery) rather than PHP since that'll mean the page won't need reloading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable DOM elements you don't want print by CSS. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

In print.css input elements #id or .class with {display:none}

You can try duplicate display your image by:

- Javascript (withour page refresh) by createElement method or JQuery .html()
- or sending form (with refresh) to server-side script ex. PHP and multiply image by for()

Elements must be visible on page (for all media or only for print) before printing.